# The time and memory problems when using Jacobian function in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I met some problems like too long time and out of memory when using Jacobian function in pytorch, but my example is so small that I don't understand why this part will be wrong. It cost me a whole day to get the jacobian when using the torch.autograd.functional.jacobian, and nearly every time I met the out of memory problem when I use the example less than 300*300(resolution). If you have ever met these problems, please contact me and it counts a lot to me. I will post more details in my train of the network sooner.

the faster use of torch.autograd.functional.jacobian and get the jacobian matrix sooner.

Comment: The error showed in console is  torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 4.00 GiB (GPU 0; 15.78 GiB total capacity; 12.58 GiB already allocated; 2.00 GiB free; 12.63 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF